# Create "$in" query with a "limit per match"?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of users and a collection of images. Each image doc stores the GUID of its user/creator. Given a set of 4 users (for example), I want to construct a query to retrieve each user's 5 latest images. Is there a "limit per criteria" operator so I can accomplish this with one request? Something like:

```
db.images.find( 
  { 'creatorGUID' : { '$in' : arrayOfUserGUIDs , '$limitPerMatch' : 5 } } 
)
```

If it's not possible with one request, what's the most efficient way to to this kind of query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, MongoDB just kind of "knows" and then returns, it doesn't deign to see how many matches there are per clause of a range query.

The only way I can think of doing this currently is to actually query for each of the `creatorGUID`s separately with a `limit(5)`.

Horrid and bad but that is the only way I can think of in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't be a bad feature though. May be worth reporting as a feature request.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet I think there prolly is one but I suck at searching the JIRA :(

Comment: I just checked and couldn't find it either. Can always report it and let 10gen mark it as duplicate if it's already in there.

Comment: I just faced the same problem. Would be much easier than to loop through db each time!